# How can I get a dataframe of frequency and time from a wav file in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, speech

i have been able to read a wave file using librosa, but was able to get a list of frequency and amplitudes which is missing the most important part "Time", i don't know how to go a raound

```
import librosa
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from librosa import display
import seaborn as sns

sns.set() # Use seaborn's default style to make attractive graphs
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 100 # Show nicely large images in this notebook

samples, sampling_rate = librosa.load('last.aac')
plt.figure(figsize=(13,4))
librosa.display.waveplot(y = samples, sr =  sampling_rate)

plt.xlabel("Time (Seconds)")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
plt.title("Time Domain Frequency")
plt.show()
print("sampling rate is :", sampling_rate)
print("Number of samples :", len(samples))

max1 = max(samples*10)
print("Maximum amplitude", round(max1, 2))

min1 = min(samples*10)
print("Minimum amplitude", round(min1, 2))

import pandas as pd
d=pd.DataFrame(samples,columns=["Amplitudes"], index=None)
d.head()


Amplitudes  frequencies
0.091039    2756.813965
-0.040613   2427.044189
-0.046945   2347.927002
-0.136473   2323.757080
0.050659    2317.414062
```

**what i really want to extract is this below**

```
Time Frequency Amplitude
0   0.00000 -57.72730
0  21.53320 -63.55554
0  43.06641 -85.05077
0  64.59961 -91.29989
0  86.13281 -83.86144
0 107.66602 -81.54240
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the sampling rate (in Hz), you can use that to create an index in seconds.  This is an example using a 4-second audio file.

```
import librosa
import pandas as pd

y,sr = librosa.load('myfile.wav')

df = pd.DataFrame(y, columns=['Amplitude'])

df.index = [(1/sr)*i for i in range(len(df.index))]

print(df.head())
print(df.tail())
```

Output:

```
          Amplitude
0.000000  -0.004855
0.000045  -0.007008
0.000091  -0.005919
0.000136  -0.006276
0.000181  -0.005805

          Amplitude
3.999773   0.000892
3.999819   0.000765
3.999864   0.000543
3.999909   0.000428
3.999955   0.000216
```

The index is now in seconds.

Just to note, where you got the `Frequencies` column isn't shown in your example, and all the plotting stuff is not relevant to the issue, so you should trim some of that for posting questions on SO.